# Ubuntu 13.10 items in dash are not selctable

Tags: 13.10, unity-dash

since the upgrade to 13.10 I can only select items in dash if all windows are closed.

Otherwise the clicks are going "through" the dash to active application e.g. browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

running `unity --reset-icons` solved the problem